# wmctrl command to create new workspace

Tags: workspace, wmctrl, i3-window-manager

Is there a wmctrl command to create a new workspace? I want to have a button at the end of my workspaces in my bar that will open a new workspace.

Here is a screenshot of my bar so you know what I am talking about.
[image]

I want to circle with the plus inside in the bottom left to create a new workspace and move me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command I was looking for is `i3-msg workspace <n>`. That will open workspace n, where n is a positive integer.

The following is a command that will open a workspace of the smallest number that is not yet open. What I mean by that is if you have workspaces 1, 2, and 4 open, it will open workspace 3.

```
i3-msg workspace $(wmctrl -d | rev | cut -c 1 | awk -v RS='\\s+' '{ a[$1] } END { for(i = 1; i in a; ++i); print i }')
```

Answer (score 0):

*spiral of hope*'s page with [`wmctrl` examples](http://spiralofhope.com/wmctrl-examples.html) has this example:

```
# Create two desktops:
wmctrl [#n -n] 1


    Switch to desktop 1

wmctrl -s 1
```

Noting

> - The programmer starts counting at 0. So 1 means the second desktop.
> - Your window manager must be configured to provide multiple desktops for this to mean anything.

So it is possible.  Making it into a reusable button may be a different question.